# Globally changing Redo to Ctrl-Shift-Z

Tags: windows, keyboard-shortcuts

Since it's a big part of my field of study, I've gotten very used to the Mac-style way of going back and forth in the history that is in Adobe applications: Ctrl-Z for Undo, and Ctrl-Shift-Z for Redo. It's much easier this way, I find, and most importantly, since I don't use such apps as often, I always get mixed up where the shortcut for Redo is Ctrl-Y, such as Microsoft Office.

And worse yet, sometimes, there's something else on Shift-Ctrl-Z. So I go back a few times (Ctrl-Z), copy some part I had right at that moment and later deleted, and do Shift-Ctrl-Z to come back to the "present" state. And then whatever Shift-Ctrl-Z does in that app is done, which destroys all "forward" steps I had. I have just lost my progress.

It's really frustrating, and causes issues. I just can't get my brain to remember "hello, you're presently in X, so don't go pressing Ctrl-Shift-Z!"

So considering this, and the fact that it's a huge pain in some apps to change shortcuts (like Microsoft Word for example), as well as the fact that I often work at school on Deep Frozen computers and don't want to spend half of the allocated time for in-class work/exams going around apps editing shortcuts, I wonder if there's some sort of global/simpler, ideally quick, solution to this.

Ideally, the solution should work on Windows Xp as well, since some of my classes will probably take place in the outdated, ugly Windows Xp computers room.

It doesn't have to do exactly what I said, but if you have an idea that would help solve my issue, I would be grateful.

Also, it's much less important, but if the above is possible, is it also possible to do the same kind of global operation to have commands such as Save As the way I'm used to? (Ctrl-shift-S)?

Comment: For Windows look into AutoHotKey, although you might need to tailor your scripts for specific apps that already use the shortcut for something else.

Comment: @Karan That looks like it's a little bit of a hassle, but not so much if I don't need to install the actual app at school each time. Do I? If not, well, might well be worth a try.

Comment: Curious which applications had this problem most often.  I personally went on a [tirade](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/issues/856) to support both Shift-Ctrl-Z and Ctrl-Y in Notepad++.  **Supporting both** seems to be the trend.

Comment: @BobStein-VisiBone I can only remember Microsoft Office. But I haven't tried a whole lot of software.

Answer (score 9):

For the specific case of Word, `File > Options > Customize Ribbon` and hit the  Customize button for keyboard shortcuts, then choose "All Commands", "EditRedoOrRepeat" and assign <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Z</kbd> to it.

Answer (score 1):

It takes a little bit of extra work, but this is pretty much what [AutoHotKey](https://autohotkey.com/) was designed for. You write scripts which capture keyboard combinations and then respond with different keyboard combos.

You would download the program, then right click on the desktop and choose "New > AutoHotKey Script".

The following script triggers <kbd>Ctrl-Y</kbd> when you type <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+Z</kbd>:

```
#NoEnv  ; Recommended for performance and compatibility with future AutoHotkey releases.
; #Warn  ; Enable warnings to assist with detecting common errors.
SendMode Input  ; Recommended for new scripts due to its superior speed and reliability.
SetWorkingDir %A_ScriptDir%  ; Ensures a consistent starting directory.

$^+z::Send ^y
```

Double click on the script to run & activate the swap.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a tool [SharpKeys](http://www.randyrants.com/sharpkeys/) that will change the windows keyboard layout. There is also a Microsoft official keyboard layout changing tool. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx

Comment: Changing the keyboard layout would not solve this; I don't think so...